# Disabling div after a click and re-enabling it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to create a JavaScript Tic-Tac-Toe as a part of FCC front end project and I'm having trouble with 2 specific areas.

1. Disabling div from being clickable until after O or X is selected. (without this function, the clicks still get registered and it says the player won with just blank boxes.
2. Disabling a div from being re-clicked once it is marked and being able to reset this once the game is over or the reset button is pressed.

I've tried different ways to achieve this but had not much success.

Here is my code:

EDIT: I've made some revision to the code to resolve the first issue.
But I'm still having trouble with the 2nd part. I can still click the boxes after it is clicked, which changes the mark on the box and messes up the Draw condition.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var user;
  var ai;
  var aiOwn = [];
  var userOwn = [];
  var currentTurn;
  var moves = 0;

  var handler = function() {
    if (user === '') {
      moves = 0;
    }
    else {
      $(this).text(currentTurn);
      moves = moves + 1;
      checkWin();
      draw();
      next();
    };
  };

  function clearBoard() {
    document.getElementById("o").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("x").disabled = false;
    $('.box').text(' ');
    moves = 0;
    user = '';
    ai = '';
  };

  function draw() {
    if (moves >= 9) {
      alert("Draw!");
      clearBoard();
    };
  };

  function checkWin() {
    switch (true) {
      case $('#1').text() === currentTurn && $('#2').text() === currentTurn &&
      $('#3').text() === currentTurn:
        alertWin();
        break;
      case $('#4').text() === currentTurn && $('#5').text() === currentTurn &&
      $('#6').text() === currentTurn:
        alertWin();
        break;
      case $('#7').text() === currentTurn && $('#8').text() === currentTurn &&
      $('#9').text() === currentTurn:
        alertWin();
        break;
      case $('#1').text() === currentTurn && $('#4').text() === currentTurn &&
      $('#7').text() === currentTurn:
        alertWin();
        break;
      case $('#2').text() === currentTurn && $('#5').text() === currentTurn &&
      $('#8').text() === currentTurn:
        alertWin();
        break;
      case $('#3').text() === currentTurn && $('#6').text() === currentTurn &&
      $('#9').text() === currentTurn:
        alertWin();
        break;
      case $('#1').text() === currentTurn && $('#4').text() === currentTurn &&
      $('#9').text() === currentTurn:
        alertWin();
        break;
      case $('#3').text() === currentTurn && $('#5').text() === currentTurn &&
      $('#7').text() === currentTurn:
        alertWin();
        break;
      default:
    }
  };

  function alertWin() {
    if (currentTurn == user) {
      alert('Player 1 Win!');
      clearBoard();
    } else {
      alert('Player 2 Wins!');
      clearBoard();
    }
  };

  $('#o').click(function() {
    document.getElementById("o").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("x").disabled = true;
    user = 'o';
    currentTurn = 'o';
    ai = 'x';
  });

  $('#x').click(function() {
    document.getElementById("o").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("x").disabled = true;
    user = 'x';
    currentTurn = 'x';
    ai = 'o';
  });

  function next() {
    if (currentTurn == user) {
      currentTurn = ai;
    } else {
      currentTurn = user;
    }
  };

  $('#reset').on('click', clearBoard);

  $('.box').on('click', handler);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #3AB567;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
* {
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
}

h1{
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

button{
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  color: black;
  margin: 10px;
}
.board {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color:#FFD2AD;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  position:relative;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #BFAC82;
}
.box{
  width: 194px;
  height: 194px;
  border:1px solid;
  border-color: white;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFD2AD;
  font-size:100px;
}
div.box:hover {
      background-color: darken(#FFD2AD, 5);
    }

div{
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div container = 'container-fluid center'>
  <h1> Tic Tac Toe </h1>
  <button id = 'o' class ='btn'> O </button>
  <button id = 'x' class ='btn'> X </button>
  <button id= 'reset' class = 'btn'>RESET</button>
  <div class = 'board'>
   <div id = '1' class="box no-element"></div>
   <div id = '2' class="box no-element"></div>
   <div id = '3' class="box no-element"></div>
   <div id = '4' class="box no-element"></div>
   <div id = '5' class="box no-element"></div>
   <div id = '6' class="box no-element"></div>
   <div id = '7' class="box no-element"></div>
   <div id = '8' class="box no-element"></div>
   <div id = '9' class="box no-element"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can't see how this game would ever work, since you disable BOTH x/o buttons once they're clicked, making it impossible to make any other moves

Comment: The x/o button is the button at the top for player choosing whether they want to be X or O for the game. While the game is played, they can click on the boxes. I'm supposed to have it so that it is machine vs player but for now I have it designed as if two players alternate turns. I'll be adding the machine part later.

Answer (score 0):

For your second part you could put in CSS like the following:

```
.myDiv
{
    pointer-events:none; 
}
```

This disables clicking inside the div

Then you can just disable it or enable it with javascript eg:

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.removeProperty("pointer-events");
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was able to fix the issue by adding an else if statement to the handler var where if the box already has an 'x' or 'o', it won't do anything and keep the number of moves the same.
But I do have a question about the CSS selector. How would you break down what you wrote. Does the styleSheets select CSS and what does the [0] stand for?